# Is it possible to use SharePoint Logger from MS P&P SharePoint 2010 Guidance Library when user is not authenticated?

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, logging, guidance, patterns-and-practices

I am working on custom authentication for SharePoint 2010. And I found very useful to use SharePoint Logger from MS P&P SharePoint 2010 Guidance Library.

It works fine when I get instance of SharePointLogger through SharePointServiceLocator only when user is already authenticated under web application and have read privileges on top level site collection. But when I try to instantiate it in ASP.NET page code-behind before user authenticate (it's a custom multilogon authentication provider selecting page) I get different errors:

1) if I use SharePointServiceLocator - I get in logs "Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005" and 403 error in browser.

2) if I run SharePointServiceLocator code under SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges I get exception in browser with stack trace, which says that ServiceLocator tried to access property bags but hasn't privileges.

3) if I use directly "new SharePointLogger()" - I get 403 in browser and nothing significant in logs.

So I decide that it's hard to use P&P SharePointLogger in this specific case. But please let me know if you have a suitable solution for this case or alternate logging approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to write to ULS, can you try this code (preferably SPRunWithElevatedPrivileges) - http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/SharePoint-2010-Log-to-ULS-from-code.aspx